# Plugin recommendation for member management

Tags: plugin-recommendation, users, user-registration

I couldn't find any plugin to do that, so I need a help here. This is what I need. One page will have a small form with 6 fields. One field is to upload photo. Another page will show in a matrix layout (2 columns 5 rows) all the users that were registered from my form. On the backend, I just need to be able to see the registered people and manage them (accept, delete, and so on).

Do you know any plugin or tutorial that show me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out http://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/ . It has front-end user registration with avatars uploads and user listing.

The one thing that it doesn't have is approve user before activating them on the site, but you can delete and edit users from the backend in the users section.